# How can I write a script that uses argument/parameter to choose what backup to run, (daily, weekly, monthly) this is a script for ZFS backup

Tags: bash, scripts, backup, zfs

I have been writing a script in BASH for ZFS, but I will have 3 different type of backups and I need a way for the user to be able to choose which one to run, I've heard it should be done using arguments and parameters but I have no clue how, I just need an example really. Ive been reading guides for arguments but I just dont see how i can use them, at first I used a else if..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Execute your script as below :

```bsh
./script.sh positional_parameter_1
```

The parameter value can be daily,monthly,weekly in your case.

Within the script you can refer to this parameter value using `$1`.

Example for daily backup:

script should be executed as

```bsh
./script.sh daily
```

Within the script you should have something like :

```bsh
if [$1 == "daily"]
then
{
   # code to take daily backup
}
fi
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me alot, great explanation!

Comment: you need space between the bracket and the statement ```[ "$1" == "daily" ]``` even better would be ```[[ $1 = daily ]]```

Comment: instead of using ```{}``` you can do ```: # code to...``` that will allow you to leave the if statement "blank"